# Tattletale (java) won't run because of a IoException

Tags: java

I wanted to search for unused pom's dependancies using tattentale
but I'm getting this when running it (after 1-2 minute of execution)

```
D:\No\tattletale-1.1.2.Final\tattletale-1.1.2.Final>java -Xmx1024m -jar tattletale.jar D:\EspaceEclipse\Checkouts\webv67x D:\No
Exception: Could not delete D:\No\tattletale-1.1.2.Final\tattletale-1.1.2.Final\javassist.jar
java.io.IOException: Could not delete D:\No\tattletale-1.1.2.Final\tattletale-1.1.2.Final\javassist.jar
        at org.jboss.tattletale.Main.recursiveDelete(Main.java:1355)
        at org.jboss.tattletale.Main.recursiveDelete(Main.java:1350)
        at org.jboss.tattletale.Main.recursiveDelete(Main.java:1350)
        at org.jboss.tattletale.Main.setupOutputDir(Main.java:1323)
        at org.jboss.tattletale.Main.execute(Main.java:548)
        at org.jboss.tattletale.Main.main(Main.java:1429)
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you check whether there are other applications holding a handle to that file? If you're on windows, try Process Explorer.

Comment: LockHunter tells me that no other processes are locking this file